# Mongoose Model.create not executing

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a mongoose model called Rating. When I want to create a new Rating, I go to the post route and call Rating.create. For some reason, Rating.create never gets executed. I copied my code from someone else, and that person's code is working. Thus, I must be missing something somewhere else in my app. Any ideas?

**Ratings.js route**

```
var express     = require("express");
var router      = express.Router({mergeParams: true});
var Campground  = require("../models/campground");
var Rating      = require("../models/rating");
var middleware  = require("../middleware");

router.post('/', middleware.isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    Campground.findById(req.params.id, function(err, campground) {
        if(err) { console.log(err); }
        console.log("REQ.BODY.RATING: ", req.body.rating); 
        if (req.body.rating) {
            console.log("IN HERE");
            Rating.create(req.body.rating, function(err, rating) {
                if(err) { console.log(err); }
                console.log("Creating rating");
                // do stuff
                req.flash("success", "Successfully added rating");
            });
        } else {
            req.flash("error", "Please select a rating");
        }
        res.redirect('/campgrounds/' + campground._id);
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

I am getting the "IN HERE" console.log printed out.... but not the "Creating rating" one or error.

**Ratings.js Model**

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var ratingSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    rating: Number,
    author: {
        id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User"
        },
        username: String
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Rating", ratingSchema);
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: `res.redirect('/campgrounds/' + campground._id);` will be called before the other async actions complete. You need to place that "inside" the callback.

Comment: Good call. Still wouldn't solve the issue though. So now I'm not getting redirected, but nothing is happening still...

Comment: `'mongoose.set('debug',true)` Add it you your listing, preferably before the connection is made. This will show you if `ratings.insert()` is actually ever getting called. If not then there likely is a problem with the model definition for `Rating`.

Comment: thanks for the tip! and yes, it's never being called

Comment: When I add

  Rating.find({}, function(err, res) {
     console.log("HERE"); 
  });

I do get the console.log and
Mongoose: ratings.find({}, { fields: {} })... so its a problem with create

Comment: `req.body.rating` is a "string"? Or perhaps it's simply not the same shape as defined in the schema. `console.log(req.body.rating)` should show you what it looks like. Check it and fix it so it actually is valid.

Answer (score 0):

first of all thats too many if statements, try this approach

```
router.post('/', middleware.isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    Campground.findById(req.params.id, function(err, campground) {
        if(err) { console.log(err); }
        else if (req.body.rating) {
            console.log("IN HERE");
            Rating.create(req.body.rating, function(err, rating) {
                if(err) { console.log(err); }
                console.log("Creating rating");
                rating.author.id = req.user._id;
                rating.author.username = req.user.username;
                rating.save();
                campground.ratings.push(rating);
                campground.save();
                // do stuff
                req.flash("success", "Successfully added rating");
            });
        } else {
            req.flash("error", "Please select a rating");
        }
        res.redirect('/campgrounds/' + campground._id);
    });
});
```

and make sure in the ejs file you name the variable as an array Object so it would create it based on that object "it cant create using just a number variable you need to pass in an array so it turns it into a Java object in the DB", just like we did in the comments as in:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="comment[text]" placeholder="text">

<input class="form-control" type="text" name="rating[rating]" placeholder="text">
```